# CSS with id and class not showing class style

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using this <kbd>CSS</kbd> code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#TicketUpdateLeft {
    border:1px solid black;
    colour:#999999;
}
#TicketUpdateLeft .Customer {
    background-colour:#000000;
}
</style>
```

and this <kbd>HTML</kbd>:

```
<div id="TicketUpdateLeft" class="Customer">test</div>
```

but the background colour is not showing as `#000000` but the border and text colour works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `color` not `colour`.

Ex: `background-color:#000000;` and `color:#999999;`

And based on your code, you do want to use `#TicketUpdateLeft.Customer` (no space between them).

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5LeXb/)**

Comment: Good eye, I missed that completely!

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have a space between `#TicketUpdateLeft .Customer` so it should be

```
#TicketUpdateLeft.Customer
```

If you are having a space between the `id` and the `class` then the meaning of the selector changes, it will look for an element having a `class` called `.Customer` which is nested inside an element having an `id` of `#TicketUpdateLeft`

Also you have spelled `color` in the wrong way, it's `color` and not `colour`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqQ69/)

---

Also, you won't need a selector like `#TicketUpdateLeft.Customer` because ID's are *unique* in the document, so over specifying isn't required, but if you are using the same `id` with different `class` in some another document, than your selector makes sense.

Comment: that makes no difference at all

Comment: @user3223205 Seriously?

Comment: @user3223205 No, Mr. Alien is correct. The space means something different then you are looking for. If you run his demo and put a space, you'll see that the background color is no longer applied.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be

`#TicketUpdateLeft.Customer`

instead of

`#TicketUpdateLeft .Customer`

The way you have it, the CSS is targeting a *child* element of `#TicketUpdateLeft` with the class `Customer`

And `colour` should be just `color`